# Measurability of maximum likelihood estimator under conditions from Lehmann's "Theory of point estimation"

Tags: st.statistics, measurable-functions

I'm trying to prove that MLE from the proof of one theorem in Lehmann's "Theory of point estimation"
(the theorem is below) is a measurable function. I know that under some regularity conditions (e.g.  stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430954/example-of-a-non-measurable-maximum-likelihood-estimator
or
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251393/when-is-the-maximum-likelihood-estimator-measurable ) MLE is measurable, but it didn't help me to prove that the closest root from the proof is a measurable function.

The problem is as follows. By definition, an estimate is a measurable function. Even the existence of a measurable version of MLE is not so obvious, but here an extremum arises over the set of MLE. It is unlikely that a theorem from a classical book can be wrong, but how to prove it?

The theorem is here:

[image]

I think that in $(3.14)$ the set $|\hat{\theta}_n - \theta_0|$ may be not measurable (but I don't know counterexample).

Comment: I wonder whether there is any difference between saying "The true parameter value is an interior point of the sample space" and saying "The parameter space contains an open set of which the true parameter value is an interior point."

Comment: @MichaelHardy If there's a typo in the first phrase and we compare "The true parameter value is an interior point of the parameter (not sample) space" and "The parameter space contains an open set of which the true parameter value is an interior point" then there's no difference, but how could it help?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't help with your question, but the author's phrasing makes the matter superficially appear more complicated than it is.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) does not have to be measurable. For instance, suppose that $f(x|\theta)=g(x-\theta)$, where $g(x)=1(0<x<1)$. Then, for any $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n$, any number $\hat\theta(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in(\max_i x_i-1,\min_i x_i)$ is a maximizer of the likelihood $f(x_1|\theta)\cdots f(x_n|\theta)$ (in real $\theta$), and it is easy to make the resulting function $\hat\theta$ non-measurable. One can also use a mollifier to make $g$ and hence the likelihood however smooth, but with the non-measurability of an MLE preserved.

However, there is no reason to worry about this. As noted on page 1163 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-11/issue-1/Optimal-order-uniform-and-nonuniform-bounds-on-the-rate-of/10.1214/17-EJS1264.full%5C), in such situations one can simply use "the corresponding outer and inner measures".

Comment: Thank you! So if $MLE$ is non-measurable then we may define consistensy of non-measurable estitamor as convergence of inner $P_{\theta}$-measure of $\{ |\hat{\theta}_n - \theta| < \delta \}$ to $0$, right? Sounds interesting! I have not seen this approach.

Comment: About $U[\theta, \theta+1]$: I tried to make counterexample with not measurable set $\{ |\theta_n - \theta| < a \}$ under conditions of theorem 3.7, using functions $f(x_i|\theta)$ such that they are constant$>0$ on some set, but I didn't successed: Lehmann's approach imply that we should take the root which is closest to $\theta_0$ and it makes the problem harder. So unfortunately, it is still not clear whether the proof from the book can be considered correct if we will not redefine consisestency for non-measurable estimator.

Comment: @BotnakovN. : The consistency can be generally defined as the convergence of $(P_\theta)^∗(|\hat\theta_n−\theta|>\delta)$ to $0$ for each real $\delta>0$. I think this will hold in all existing theorems about MLE consistency, and this will be at least formally stronger than the statement that $P_\theta(|\hat\theta_n−\theta|>\delta)\to0$ for all measurable versions of $\hat\theta_n$ and for each real $\delta>0$.

Comment: @BotnakovN. : The condition that we should take the root closest to $\theta_0$ makes no sense statistically, because $\theta_0$ is unknown, and then $\hat\theta_n$ will not be an estimator in any sense, be it measurable or not -- because an estimator cannot depend on an unknown parameter. However, indeed it appears harder to get a counterexample with this additional "closest" condition. But, given what has been said here, do we really need such a counterexample? Anyhow, generally, I do not think Lehmann's book is quite rigorous. It is a statistical book, not really mathematical.

Comment: @BotnakovN. : Also, in Lehmann's proof, it is said "Let $\theta_n^*$ be the root [of (3.12)? -- I.P.] closest to $\theta_0$. [This exists because the limit of a sequence of roots is again a root by the continuity of of $l(\theta)$.]" Here one can say the following: (i) for the closest root to $\theta_0$ of $l'(\theta)=0$ to exist, one needs -- not the continuity of $l(\theta)$ -- but continuity of $l'(\theta)$; (ii) it is unclear why such a closest root must be a maximizer of $l(\theta)$; (iii) it is unclear why such a closest root is unique.

Comment: Previous comment continued: So, there are a number of problems with Lehmann's proof -- which I think are worse than the possible non-measurability.

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis, thank you for pointing out that there are other mistakes! I didn't notice in (i) that we use the continuity of $l'(\theta)$. In (ii) and (iii) we may somehow cope with these problems (e.g. in (ii) we may speak about root and not promise that it's maximazer, in (iii) we may take left closest root), but for (i) we need an extra assumption of continuity of $l'$.

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis, I agree that $\hat{\theta}_n$ is not an estimate (since it depends on $\theta_0$). It was interesting if $\hat{\theta}_n$ is measurable because of the corollary 3.8. This corollary states that if likelihood equation has a unique root for all $n, X_1, \dots, X_n$ and if assumptions of theorem 3.7 hold true then $\hat{\theta}_n$ is a consistent estimator. It helps to cope with the problem of dependence of $\theta_0$ and the onliest problem is measurability of $\hat{\theta}_n$.

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis, I was afraid that I didn't notice some simple reason why $\hat{\theta}_n$ is measurable. Now I'm inclined to believe that the simple thing that was not noticed is that it's not a good idea to treat "Theory of point estimation" as a rigorous book) Thank you very much!